# Conversion from int to DeafultBlockParameter

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java

I am using Infura and **web3j** to query the Ethereum blockchain. My aim is to get information about certain blocks so i'm using the function **web3.eth.getBlockByNumber**, however it gives me incompatible types error: int cannot be converted to DefaultBlockParameter. How can we convert an integer to default block parameter? Current code:

```
System.out.println("here " +web3j.ethGetBlockByNumber(6777, true));
```

I have also tried converting 6777 to BigInteger but it gives me **incompatible types** error on that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

web3j uses a DefaultBlockParameter type to encode the block number in such calls, likely to handle the "latest" and "pending" block state special  cases. Try:

```
System.out.println("here " +web3j.ethGetBlockByNumber(new DefaultBlockParameter(6777), true));
```